# How to run a walker from scratch instead of its yielded state in Jaseci?

Tags: jaseci

I am building conversational AI in jaseci using the jac language. and I run into this interesting case. Say I have a walker that has been yielded, and when I run walker run on the same walker again it will pick up from its yielded state and continue on the next node and retaining its `has` variable contexts.

I am wondering, is there a way to force the walker to start from scratch instead, with a fresh context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two possibilities to do this in Jaseci. First, if you want to completely reset the walker and not retain any of its yielded state, or second, you want that instance of the walker to remain yielded but call a fresh instance of the same walker.

In the first case (complete walker reset):

Use the `/js/walker_yield_clear` to clear all yielded walkers, or `/js/walker_yeild_delete` to remove a specific walker by its name. Of course, if you are using jsctl those Apis map to `walker yield clear` and `walker yield delete` in the command line interface.

In the second case (retain yielded walker but create new instance of a fresh walker to execute):

Use the `js/walker_spawn_create` Apis to spawn a walker instance and get it's uuid and then call `js\walker_execute` on that uuid (not `walker_run`).

Note! You'll have to be sure to clean up walkers created using these Apis manually using `/js/walker_spawn_delete`. See all the `/js/walker_spawn_*` Apis for a sense of other useful apis to manage walkers manually.

Also keep in mind you can access these Api in the Jac language itself using the `jaseci.*` standard action library (as of version 1.3.5.* at least).

Comment: oh i see. yea this works. Is there a place where I can go to check out the full spec of available Jaseci APIS?

Comment: yeah, there are live api docs here: https://api.jaseci.org/docs/